# pandas update dataframe row with new value

Tags: python, pandas

I have a text file which has been read into pandas by `df1 = pandas.read_csv(r'fruits.txt', sep=',')`

```
    item  freshness
0   apple    2.2
1   pear     0.0
```

and a series of calculations that would yield the result of `apple = 2.3`

Is it possible to do a `pandas.update` so that I can update the value of `freshness` for `apple` in the dataframe to `2.3`?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

IIUC you need [`loc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html):

```
apple = 2.3

print df['item'] == 'apple'
0     True
1    False
Name: item, dtype: bool

df.loc[df['item'] == 'apple', 'freshness'] = apple
print df
    item  freshness
0  apple        2.3
1   pear        0.0
```